# How to abort a long request in Django and stop processing?

Tags: django

There might be cases in my API when a single request will take more than 10 seconds, in which case I want to abort the processing and return some error.
I've done some research and I know that just aborting the request to the server is not enough, and that won't be pushed to the Django server.

I was wondering whether there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gunicorn for this. Gunicorn has the capability to abort all the requests taking longer than the given time duration

You can install gunicorn using:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

and here is the documentation:
https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=timeout#timeout

Command:

```
gunicorn mydjangoproject.wsgi:application --timeout 10
```